# Unable to load event data - in gmail when .ics sent using Java

Tags: java, email, icalendar

I am sending mail with .ics file using Java. But getting this error in gmail - "Unable to load event data"

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n");
            sb.append("PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN\n");
            sb.append("VERSION:2.0\n");
            sb.append("METHOD:REQUEST\n");
            sb.append("BEGIN:VEVENT\n");
```

Do I need to change

```
           sb.append("PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN\n");
```

to

```
           sb.append("PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN\n");
```

But it wont work in outlook.

My question is - is there any way to we keep both ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that, it was happening because organizer and recipient was same in that case.

Comment: Same happened for me. What a debugging nightmare...

Answer (score 1):

Calendar Events has been deleted..So that only it's showing unable to load event data error...The deleted calendar events are stored in calendar bin...you can restore it..So that you can avoid the error.by M.R.Archana Jenis